# How to stack the data in R in the following format?

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
  inten      new.probes
  12.28280      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at
  12.35039      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at
  12.38397      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at
  12.36304      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at
  12.16271      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at
  12.70304      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at
  12.28280      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at
  12.35039      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at
  12.38397      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at
  12.36304      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at
  12.16271      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at
  12.70304      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at 
  12.16271      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at
  12.70304      AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at
```

(The above is in the form as two separate columns with the probenames as one column and signal intensity values as other)
And I want the data frame to be converted the following way:

```
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at 12.28280 12.35039  12.38397  12.36304   12.16271 
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at 12.28280 12.35039  12.38397  12.36304   12.16271 
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at 12.38304 12.36304  12.38397  12.16271   12.70304
```

Any suggestions are welcome. It is a large datset and I have only given a fraction of it for help.

Comment: Did you try something ?? any code ?

Comment: Do you have always 5 values for each probe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had the same number of elements for value of `new.probes`, you could have used:

```
do.call(rbind, unstack(dat))
                        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at 12.16271 12.70304 12.16271 12.70304 12.16271
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at 12.70304 12.28280 12.35039 12.38397 12.36304
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at 12.28280 12.35039 12.38397 12.36304 12.16271
Warning message:
In function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

But this is clearly wrong - you need to pad the shorter vectors with `NA`:

```
x <- unstack(dat)
m <- max(sapply(x, length))
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(x)c(x, rep(NA, m-length(x)))))

                        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at 12.16271 12.70304 12.16271 12.70304       NA
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at 12.70304 12.28280 12.35039 12.38397 12.36304
AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at 12.28280 12.35039 12.38397 12.36304 12.16271
```

Comment: I always have 53 values and around 22800 probes

Comment: @DhivyaaReddy In that case `do.call(rbind, unstack(dat))` should work just fine.

Comment: @Andrie, I like your solution, but this strikes me as another `reshape()` problem, but one where the "times" are missing. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11938879/1270695).

Comment: Of course, I missed the comment that says they always have the same number of values, in which case, this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this problem:

1. Make sure that the `new.probes` variable is sorted.
2. Use `sequence()` and `rle()` to generate a "time" variable for each `new.probes`.
3. Use `reshape()` to transform the data.

Here's a worked example with your sample data (assuming it's named "DF").

```
DF = DF[order(DF$new.probes), ]
DF$time = sequence(rle(as.vector(DF$new.probes))$lengths)
reshape(DF, direction = "wide", idvar = "new.probes", timevar = "time")
#             new.probes  inten.1  inten.2  inten.3  inten.4  inten.5
# 11 AFFX-r2-P1-cre-2_at 12.16271 12.70304 12.16271 12.70304       NA
# 6  AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at 12.70304 12.28280 12.35039 12.38397 12.36304
# 1  AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at 12.28280 12.35039 12.38397 12.36304 12.16271
```

Or, if you prefer the syntax in `reshape2` to base R's `reshape`, replace step 3 with:

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(DF, new.probes ~ time, value.var = "inten")
```